# User pace test mix and constant load pattern

Tags: visual-studio-2013, performance-testing, load-testing

I have a load test with a test mix with two tests. Each test is set to 10 Tests Per User Per Hour. I also have a Constant Load Pattern, with a Constant User Count of 10. I run the test for 1 hour. I would expect each of my tests to run approximately 50 times: 10 tests per hour * (10 users / 2 tests). However, the test results show that one of the tests only ran 10 times (average test time 1989 seconds), and the other test only ran 21 times (average test time 131 seconds). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1989 seconds is about 33 minutes, which means a virtual user needs 66 minutes for two iterations of this test. So it is impossible for this test to be run at 10 per user per hour.

131 seconds for the other test gives the possibility of (1 hour)/(131 seconds) tests per hour, ie 1*60*60/131 which is about 27. So this test could be run at 10 per user per hour; in fact it could be run at nearly three times that rate.

You cannot set individual tests to run with pacing. Pacing applies to all the tests in a scenario.

10 executions at 1989 seconds plus 21 executions at 131 seconds is a total of 10*1989+21*131 seconds, ie about 6 hours 17 minutes. Having 10 virtual users running for 1 hour gives 10 hours of total execution time available. The numbers of test executions shown in the test results exclude any incomplete tests that are abandoned when the test period finishes. Hence each of the ten virtual users could be busy when the test completes. These uncounted tests plus the pause between short test executions could easily account for the difference between 6h17m and 10h.

The effect of pacing probably means that after running a 131 second test that virtual user pauses until time for the next of the 10 executions per hour. Thus each 131 second test is followed by a (1 hour)/(10 executions per hour)-(131 seconds) pause, ie 60*60/10-131 = 360-131 = 219 seconds.

The underlying problem would seem to be that one of the tests is incompatible with the specified pacing rate. To see how and when each the tests were executed look at the "Details" page in the results. You can expand the sliders at the bottom to see the entire test duration, or to focus on sections of it. You can also adjust the filters in the top-left-hand pane to show/hide individual tests, also to highlight tests that failed. Studying the "Details" page should show you clearly which virtual users ran which tests and how Visual Studio tried to use the pacing instructions given.

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful. I had not realised there were sliders for the Virtual User Activity Chart. The chart appeared to be empty, so I assumed no data had been collected for the vusers. In fact the right slider was at the minimum! I can see now what you are saying about one test being so long that there is not enough time to run it again.